# Creating a Plugin System in Java

Tags: java, plugins, system

I am attempting to make a game using java, and I need a plugin system for the server...

How might I make it so that there is a folder named plugins that the users can simply drop jar files in there and I can call functions within those jar files all at once?

This is implying that a community would make plugins that I don't know about (so i need to have it run all plugins even if I don't know the plugins name)

(I would appreciate it if I didn't need to use someone else's framework like jspf)

Comment: While the accepted answer is great, I would personally be very grateful for another answer that doesn't use a framework. The reason for this is (1) I want to understand how this is done and (2) there might be an instance in which I require something that JSPF doesn't provide.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Writing your own plug-in infrastructure is fun, but totally unneccesary.  It's a solved problem and you're not going to write a higher quality one than one that already exists and is proven in the field.  I'd say choose your battles.

I've tried out [JSPF](http://code.google.com/p/jspf/) before and found it incredibly easy to use.  And this coming from someone who has done **exactly** what you're trying to do:  I've made my own plug-in infrastructure (for basically the same purpose: to load mini-games dynamically) from scratch, writing the classloading and framework myself.  And if I were to do it again, I would use a framework like JSPF without hesitation.

To load all classes from jars in a directory that adhere to a certain interface (say `Game`), it's as easy as:

```
PluginManager pm = PluginManagerFactory.createPluginManager();
pm.addPluginsFrom(new File("plugins/").toURI());

Collection<Game> games = new PluginManagerUtil(pm).getPlugins(Game.class);
```

IIRC the only requirement on implementers of `Game` is that it be tagged with the `@PluginImplementation` annotation.

### Edit

And then:

```
for ( Game game : games ) {
   game.someMethod();
}
```

Comment: @blazingkin: You don't know how to write a for-loop?  I'll add one to my answer.  And sorry I didn't see the last bit in your question about JSPF, but it honestly is incredibly simple to use.  Writing your own plug-in infrastructure is a much larger task than suits StackOverflow questions.  It involves writing custom classloaders, etc.

Comment: sorry about that your post was really helpful, for some reason it displayed as something else that just said use JSPF (did you edit it or something?)